# How to get the text of a binding inside a repeater in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Using this [example web](http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/), how could I get the value of `{{result.first}}` with **Protractor**? That one is inside a repeater, so I can't accesss it by a binding.

This is an example where I want to use that value.

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl" class="container">
    <div>
      <h3>Super Calculator</h3>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input ng-model="first" type="text" class="input-small"/>
        <select ng-model="operator" class="span1"
                ng-options="value for (key, value) in operators">
        </select>
        <input ng-model="second" type="text" class="input-small"/>
        <button ng-click="doAddition()" id="gobutton" class="btn">Go!</button>
        <h2>{{latest}}</h2>
      </form>
    </div>
    <h4>History</h4>
    <table class="table">
      <thead><tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Expression</th>
        <th>Result</th>
      </tr></thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="result in memory">
        <td>
          {{result.timestamp | date:'mediumTime'}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>{{result.first}}</span>
          <span>{{result.operator}}</span>
          <span>{{result.second}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>{{result.value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the Protractor code:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
  var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
  var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
  var latestResult = element(by.binding('latest'));
  var history = element.all(by.repeater('result in memory'));

  function add(a, b) {
    firstNumber.sendKeys(a);
    secondNumber.sendKeys(b);
    goButton.click();
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('should have a history', function() {
    add(1, 2);
    add(3, 4);

    expect(history.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the html code that you want the value from? Or can you explain which value are you looking for in the web address that you have mentioned in the question? Please update the details in your question. Thanks

Comment: I pasted the incorrect link and now is fixed, thanks.

Comment: So, your issue is resolved now? Or is there a problem yet?

Comment: @GirishSortur It's all resolved now with his new comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read more in the [API](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) for protractor, and about [repeaters](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater)

```
element.all(by.repeater('result in results')).first()
element.all(by.repeater('result in results')).get(0)
```

both will return the first result, for each element inside of that, chain it with `element.all(by.repeater('result in results')).first().element...`

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way to access that binding directly?

Comment: @J.J.Bocanegra yes there is, but it's a 'ElementFinderArray' so you should get the array, and find your element there, like so: `element.all(by.binding("result.first")).first()//or .get() or then(function(array) {}); if you want to do more on that.`